# DBCA Oracle in silent mode not display anything when send

Tags: linux, oracle, ssh, database-administration

I'm getting a very strange error in `Oracle DBCA`.

I'm using [this](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMIN/create.htm#ADMIN12479) oracle guide to create a `DB` with `DBCA`. I'm trying to run the first example of this guide to create a `DB` but when I click the `enter` button after entering the command, the linux prompt doesn't display anything. Every row printed before is erased and the prompt remains totally black.

Why is this happening? What am I doing wrong?

I connect to the db host remotely with `ssh`. I have a Windows machine and the remote host is Centos machine. I used `git bash` to launch `ssh`.

Comment: You can not simply use command line SSH tools to display GUI application. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/190200/how-can-i-remotely-access-my-linux-gui

Comment: It's Wright i used Xming with putty and dbca worked fine. But not in silent mode (of course) but in interactive mode with Window.

Comment: For silent mode you can simply use ssh command line tools.